Can I use MDT to capture the OS of the reference machine locally? (The OS MDT is running on)
I have searched this topic up and down and have found zero answers. I understand that most use MDT in a domain environment, but I am working locally and offline with no network. I have watched videos and read about how to set up a Deployment Share 'C:\DeploymentShareCapture' and have everything working all the way up to running LiteTouch.vbs locally and selecting 'Capture an image of this reference computer'.  The Location is auto filling and when I click next I get an
ERROR: Unable to connect to UNC path.
I have been attempting to fix this with zero result.  When I watch videos on how to do this, everyone is connecting to a \\Server\Deployment Share, but I want to do this locally.  I have learned that if I update the Rules tab on the 'DeploymentShareCaputre' I need to choose the 'Completely regenerate the boot images', or I get an Invalid Credentials error when I launch LiteTouch.vbs.  I have tried to edit the bootstrap.ini with a deployroot=my share path, but that also causes the Invalid Credentials error.  When I remove the updated deployroot=my share path, the capture task sequence launches ok, but then I get the UNC path error.
I only have one computer and that is my test environment.  I have configured a reference machine and I want to capture this machine to deploy these settings to multiple devices.  However, I have to work locally and don't have a network.  In my head, I thought if I installed MDT on this machine I would be able to run LiteTouch.vbs with a 'Sysprep and Capture' task sequence which would capture the local OS.  However, I see my problem is that MDT wants to reach out through a network and capture something else.  Is there a way to tell MDT to Capture the local machine that it lives on.  Or, am I an idiot and totally off base.  Here is my configuration and I am obviously doing something wrong.
C:\DeploymentShareCapture
Description: MDT Deployment Share Capture
Network (UNC) path: \DESKTOP-VR088BQ\DeploymentShareCapture$ (which is my local machine name)
Local Path: C:\DeploymentShareCapture
Rules Tab
[Settings]
Priority=Default
Properties=MyCustomProperty
[Default]
OSInstall=Y
DoCapture=YES
SkipCapture=NO
SkipAdminPassword=YES
SkipProductKey=YES
SkipComputerBackup=NO
SkipBitLocker=NO
Edit Bootstrap.ini
[Settings]
Priority=Default
[Default]
(when I had a Deployroot=UNCpath the capture task sequence doesn't launch)
I have also imported the OS I am trying to capture and setup a Sysprep and Capture Task sequence.
I appreciate any help and guidance on placing me on the proper path.
